# Email.js not returns an error on Node.js backend server

Tags: javascript, node.js, email

I'm using [email.js](https://www.emailjs.com/) to send emails from my server with Node.js and Express. Email.js has an npm package so I imported it using `const emailjs = require("emailjs")`. However, I get an error:

```
Instead change the require of email.js in Mycomputer\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
   at Object.<anonymous> (Mycomputer\index.js:4:17) {
 code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

What is a `dynamic import`? How do I use it with my project? This code works fine on the client using  `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@emailjs/browser@3/dist/email.min.js"></script>`

Here's my code:

```
const { response } = require("express")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const emailjs = require("emailjs")

const port = 3000
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at port ${port}`)
})

app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use(express.json({limit: "1mb"}))

app.post("/email", (request, response) => {

    (function () {
        // https://dashboard.emailjs.com/admin/account
        emailjs.init("My top secret API key")
    })();

    const sendContactData = (parmas) => {
        const tempParmas = {
            from_name: request.body.from_name,
            reply_to: request.body.reply_to,
            subject: request.body.from_namerequest.body.subject,
            message: request.body.message,
        }

        emailjs.send("My top secret service ID", "My top secret template", tempParmas).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            response.send("Success!")
        })

    }
    response.send("Success!")
    console.log(request.body)
})
```

Comment: Have you tried googling what a dynamic import is? Try "js dynamic import vs require". You probably want to to `const emailjs = await import("./emailjs.js")`.

Comment: @Slight ```const emailjs = await import("./emailjs.js")``` return a ```type error``` ```TypeError: ImportCall("./emailjs.js") is not a function```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `emailjs-com` is deprecated and no longer supports newer versions of Node.js. Install `@emailjs/browser` by using this command: `npm install @emailjs/browser --save`.

You must also replace `const emailjs = require("emailjs")` with `const emailjs = require("@emailjs/browser")` to import the correct package. Then your import should work as expected.